# Azure Pipeline yaml : how to inform user that condition are not met?

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

I setup a release.yml with condition. It works like a charm but I wonder how can I inform final user that condition are not met.

Please see below screenshot where *test* stage is not started
[image]

Log details shows the following:
[image]

Do you have any ninja tip to show to user why *test* stage is skipped ? For instance it should display that condition xxx is not met.

Regards,
Paul